# Linux kernel for A20 cpu stuck at 'Starting kernel'

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot

Linux kernel version: 4.1.8
board:cubietruck with A20 CPU.
compiled platform: os x 10.5.5

I do as follows:

First I use sunxi_defconfig as the default configuration, but 'byte_swap.h' not found error occurred. Then I use a sun7i_defconfig which offered by cubieboard, and then `make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- zImage`,`make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- dtbs`.

Then I burn the Uboot and the spl to the SDCard and make to partitions: one for boot and one for root file system. I put the zImage, script.bin and the dtb file on the boot partition.

Then I create boot.cmd as below:

```
fatload mmc 0 0x46000000 zImage
fatload mmc 0 0x49000000 sun7i-a20-cubietruck.dtb
setenv bootargs console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait panic=10 ${extra}
bootz 0x46000000 - 0x49000000
```

and then `mkimage -C none -A arm -T script -d boot.cmd boot.scr`.

so there's three files on the boot partition:

boot.scr

script.bin

sun7i-a20-cubietruck.dtb

zImage

the Uboot works fine.(At least I think), here is the output

```
U-Boot SPL 2014.04 (Sep 29 2015 - 21:36:09)
Board: Cubietruck
DRAM: 2048 MiB
CPU: 960000000Hz, AXI/AHB/APB: 3/2/2
spl: not an uImage at 1600


U-Boot 2014.04 (Sep 29 2015 - 21:36:09) Allwinner Technology

CPU:   Allwinner A20 (SUN7I)
Board: Cubietruck
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  2 GiB
MMC:   SUNXI SD/MMC: 0
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   dwmac.1c50000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
reading uEnv.txt
** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
reading boot.scr
281 bytes read in 16 ms (16.6 KiB/s)
Jumping to boot.scr
## Executing script at 44000000
reading zImage
3446280 bytes read in 192 ms (17.1 MiB/s)
reading sun7i-a20-cubietruck.dtb
26288 bytes read in 30 ms (855.5 KiB/s)
Kernel image @ 0x46000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x349608 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 49000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x49000000
   Loading Device Tree to 4fff6000, end 4ffff6af ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Any one could help?

Comment: Seems like Allwinner kernels will try to silently decompress.  So your only hope of a progress indicator is the kernel printk()s.  There is one problem you need to fix in the **boot.cmd** file.  In the third line, you need to *remove* the square braces surrounding the "earlyprintk" parameter.  Hopefully your kernel is configured with earlyprintk enabled.

Comment: The square braces is a typo, thanks for pointing out. So the suggestion is insert printk in the kernel?? I don't even think the kernel is got excecute. So would you plz show more detail what should I do?

Comment: Your sole indicator of whether the kernel has started (or not) depends on (unfortunately) the *earlyprintk* feature (since Allwinner kernels will silently decompress).  So make sure that the **bootargs** are correct and *earlyprintk* is enabled in the kernel config (by default it's disabled).  Rebuild the kernel if necessary.

Comment: Are you following some tutorial?  Your selection of toolchain is a bit unusual, i.e. `arm-none-eabi-`.  For building Linux on an Allwinner A20 SoC with Cortex-A7 CPU, a toolchain with the prefix `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` would seem more appropriate IMO

Comment: @sawdust I use a Mac to compile the kernel, the arm-none-eabi is tool chain. And I am new to kernel, so can you give me some suggestions where to put printk?

Comment: *"I am new to kernel"* -- If you want help, then respond to questions with salient information.  For the last time, is earlyprintk enabled in the kernel config?